# В телеграмм боте при отправке файла(фото) бот переворачивает фото

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Сперва вот код Бота

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['document'])
def get_docs(message):
    file_info = bot.get_file(message.document.file_id)
    downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
    src = 'photos/' + message.document.file_name
    with open("photos/document.png", 'wb') as new_file:
        new_file.write(downloaded_file)
        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        button_update = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Улучшение", callback_data="update")
        button_bwt = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Ч\Б Фильтр", callback_data="bwt")
        keyboard.add(button_update, button_bwt)
        bot.reply_to(message, 'Что будем делать?',reply_markup=keyboard)
        # Кнопки
        @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True)
        def answer(call):
# Что будет происходить после нажатие на "Ч\Б Фильтр"
            if call.data == 'bwt':
                # Цветность( делаем 0 для получении эффекта черно\белое)
                imageb = Image.open('photos/documentbw.jpg')
                esh = ImageEnhance.Color(imageb)
                color = 0
                imageb_color = esh.enhance(color)
                imageb_color.save('photos/documentbw.jpg')
                # Автоконтраст мелких точек
                km = Image.open("photos/documentbw.jpg")
                PIL.ImageOps.autocontrast(km, cutoff=0, ignore=None).save("photos/documentbw.jpg")
                # Отправка фото
                verjnakan = open('photos/documentbw.jpg', 'rb')
                chat_id=call.message.chat.id
                testik = bot.send_document(chat_id, verjnakan)
                bot.edit_message_text(text=testik)
```

При отправке файла почему-то переворачивает изображение
Вот что происходит у пользователя
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Первый файл (который был отправлен через телефон(Самсунг Так как у других производителях такого нету)

Второй файл уже был через онлайн конвертор конвертирован в формат .jpg а потом отправлен

А вот эти файлы (может поможет в данной ситуации)

Это с телефона -[image]

А это через конвертор -[image]

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Попробовал в питоне перевернуть через Image.rotate на 360 градусов потом сохранить (не помогло)

Попробовал сменить формат на .png  (не помогло)

Через Pillow тоже попробовал конвертировать потом сохранить тоже (не помогло)

Comment: Скорее всего в файле картинки записано в какой ориентации было снято и телеграм это как-то обрабатывает. Попробуйте посмотреть теги EXIF у проблемной картинки

Comment: Спасибо попробую

Comment: Здравствуйте. В проблемном картинке Orientation - 6 а у нормальной Orientation 1 может из-за этого?

Comment: Мб, попробуйте удалял этот тег перед тем как его отправить в телеграм. Думаю, можно вообще чистить EXIF -- эти теги дополнительные и нечего их знать кому-то (например, там можно быть данные геолокации, не думаю что об этом нужно кому-то либо знать)

Comment: Оформите решение в ответе :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Решено!

**Добрый вечер вчера была проблема связанной с ориентацией картинки (бот автоматический переворачивает фото потом отправляет)**

Помог в данной ситуации **Pillow** с модулем **ImageOps**

**Вот сам код который возвращает файл в том виде в котором была отправлена пользователем**

```
from PIL import Image , ImageOps
photo = Image.open("директория вашей фотографии")
ImageOps.exif_transpose(photo).save('где будет сохранить')
```

Comment: Как хорошо, что ты нашел ответ) теперь и я его знаю! Спасибо!